# Why does Textarea width and DIV width behave so differently?

Tags: html, css, width, textarea

I have a series of `div` boxes followed by a `textarea` with the same class to adopt the same styling but I've noticed that the `div` seems to automatically fill the horizontal width of the parent whilst the `textarea` doesn't. Giving the `textarea` `width:100%` solves the problem but then if I give the shared class `margin-left:80px`, the `textarea` exceeds the parent whilst the `div` boxes do not.

I'm simply wondering why this behaviour occurs and if it can be replicated with the `textarea`. The cleanest solution I have so far is giving the `textarea` `width:calc(100%-80px)` but would prefer a more 'natural' solution.

Here's some example code:-

***HTML***

```
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="box">
        DIV
        </div>

        <div class="box">
        DIV
        </div>

        <form>
            <textarea class="box">TEXTAREA</textarea>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
```

***CSS***

```
.container {
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  height: 80px;
  background: #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 0 50px 80px
}

textarea {
   width: calc(100% - 80px); // CLEANISH SOLUTION
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tndm2eqz/1/

Answer (score 2):

it does apply CSS given, but `<form>` is in between so `width` is not inherited prperly : https://jsfiddle.net/tndm2eqz/3/

```css
.container {
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  height: 80px;
  background: #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 0 50px 80px;
}

form {
  margin: 0 0 50px 80px;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="box">
      DIV
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      DIV
    </div>

    <form>
      <textarea class="box">TEXTAREA</textarea>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your solution is also adding `width: 100%;` and `box-sizing: border-box;`. Why?

Comment: Surely the inheritance should be passed down `textarea` through `form`? I've also attempted to specify `width:inherit` and also `width:100%` for both the `form` and the `textarea` but neither have produced the desired result, why is this?

Comment: @DarkDust box-sizing was already set for .box anyway  , it includes borders and padding  into width calculation ...wich textarea has by default

Comment: @Alluziion inherit for width only works if parent has a width set, wich form doesn't . form has margin and is block , so no need to set width:100%. textarea has default size , even display:block do not overide it. /  you had width:100% + margin from .box wich was in fact 100% window's width + 80px , much too much ;) , so we  give the margin to form, and ask textarea to fill entire width  avalaible in form :)

Answer (score 0):

textarea is not `display:block` by default u have to add `display:block` and `width:100%;` to your textarea so, why don't you take textarea inside .box div and make textarea width:100% with block. For example

```css
.container {
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box,.box textarea  {
  height: 80px;
  background: #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box{
  margin: 0 0 50px 80px;

}
.box textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"> DIV </div>
    <div class="box"> DIV </div>
    <form>
        <div class="box">
            <textarea>TEXTAREA</textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You've changed the HTML structure. I think the point is to make it look the same while _retaining_ the structure to understand why the sizing is different.

Answer (score 0):

The `div` displaying type is `block` unlike `textarea`. If you want the `textarea` to behave as `div`, add this:

```
textarea{
    display: block;
}
```

And don't forget about `textarea`'s borders and shadows.

Comment: Adding `display:block` to `textarea` makes no difference to the result in the JSFiddle that I provided. I've also tried several other display values with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .container {
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

.box {
  height: 80px;
  background: #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
 <body>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    DIV
    </div>

    <div class="box">
    DIV
    </div>

    <form>
      <textarea class="box" rows="10">TEXTAREA</textarea>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Just some code without any explanation is almost useless. Please explain what you've changed and why.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've found a solution, but I'm going to add a solution that it fit with my case.

I had a `textarea` inside a `div` and I wanted to set `height` for the `textarea` like usually I set it for divs, and I noticed adding a `box-sizing:content-box` in the `textarea` style works making the `textarea` behavior similar to a `div`.

Hope someone can find this answer useful.

Thank you